# creating a slide down search form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, search

I am trying to create a search form in my navigation bar.  I want a little magnifying glass symbol in my navigation bar and when you press on the symbol a search form will drop down ( like this site - http://goodlife.fuelthemes.net ).  I have added the search form with the symbol to my theme however I can't figure out how to add the drop down function.  Does anyone have any solutions? Thanks in advance.

header.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme.
 *
 * @package Total
 */

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="ht-page">
<header id="ht-masthead" class="ht-site-header">
<div class="ht-container ht-clearfix">
<div id="ht-site-branding">
<?php 
if ( function_exists( 'has_custom_logo' ) && has_custom_logo() ) :
the_custom_logo();
else : 
if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>
<h1 class="ht-site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
<?php else : ?>
<p class="ht-site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<p class="ht-site-description"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
    <div class="search-toggle">
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div>
</div><!-- .site-branding -->

<nav id="ht-site-navigation" class="ht-main-navigation">
<div class="toggle-bar"><span></span></div>
<?php 
wp_nav_menu( array( 
'theme_location' => 'primary', 
'container_class' => 'ht-menu ht-clearfix' ,
'menu_class' => 'ht-clearfix',
'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
) ); 
?>
</nav><!-- #ht-site-navigation -->
</div>
</header><!-- #ht-masthead -->

<div id="ht-content" class="ht-site-content ht-clearfix">
```

searchform.php

```html
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<label>
<span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
<input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" />
</label>
<input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

css

```html
#ht-masthead .search-form {
position: absolute;
right: 200px;
top: 200px;
}

#ht-masthead .search-field {
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url(images/search-icon.png);
background-position: 5px center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 24px 24px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
height: 37px;
margin: 3px 0;
padding: 0 0 0 34px;
position: relative;
-webkit-transition: width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
transition:         width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
width: 0;
}

#ht-masthead .search-field:focus {
background-color: #fff;
border: 2px solid #c3c0ab;
cursor: text;
outline: 0;
width: 230px;
}
.search-form
.search-submit { 
display:none;
}
```

updated css*

```html
#ht-masthead .search-field {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(images/search-icon.png);
    background-position: 5px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 24px 24px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 37px;
    margin: 3px 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 34px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
    transition:         width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
    width: 230px;
}

#ht-masthead .search-field:focus {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #c3c0ab;
    cursor: text;
    outline: 0;
}
#ht-masthead .search-form {
display:none;
position: absolute;
right: 200px;
top: 200px;
}
.search-toggle:hover #ht-masthead .search-form{
display:block;
}
.search-form
.search-submit { 
display:none;
}
```

updated search form.php*

```html
<div class="search-field"></div>
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<label>
<span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
<input type="search" class="" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" />
</label>
<input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Drop down Search box]

you can achieve this with two methods:

1. Javascript way
2. CSS way

CSS way:
this is your search container style

```css
#ht-masthead .search-form {
position: absolute;
right: 200px;
top: 200px;
}
```

Edit:

```css
#ht-masthead .search-form {
display:none;
position: absolute;
right: 200px;
top: 200px;
}
```

You should style your searchToggle like this

```css
.search-toggle:hover #ht-masthead .search-form{
display:block;
}
```

JavaScript Way:
Let's assume you are using jquery, it will make it easy for you by the lines of code you can use to achieve this:

```
<script>
    $(".search-toggle").click(function(){
    // We have to change the display of your search conatiner
    $("#ht-masthead .search-form).fadeToggle();
    });
</script>
```

EDITED:
Make this modification and see the output

```
<div class="search-field"></div>
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<label>
<span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
<input type="search" class="" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" />
</label>
<input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

```css
#ht-masthead .search-field {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(images/search-icon.png);
    background-position: 5px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 24px 24px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 37px;
    margin: 3px 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 34px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
    transition:         width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
    width: 230px;
}

#ht-masthead .search-field:focus {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #c3c0ab;
    cursor: text;
    outline: 0;
}
```

The problem is that your icon is displaying the icon and its nested in the `<form>` tag which we set to display:none so the icon will disappear with it too. Try the example I posted as edit and find a way to adjust it to your design.

NEW EDIT:
Add this to your css style

```
  .search-field:hover #ht-masthead .search-form{
display:block;
  }
```

JavaScript Way:
sorry my bad, we forgot to make the search field div clickable.
If your comfortable with jquery it can be easy to add click event to it, just do:

```
<script>
    $(".search-field").click(function(){
    // We have to change the display of your search conatiner
    $("#ht-masthead .search-form).fadeToggle();
    });
</script>
```

.......
Then add the anchor link to the search field div

```
<a href="#"><div class="search-field"></div>
```

Comment: I've tried doing this with the css but the search icon has disappeared.

Comment: I've posted my edits to my question.  It still did not work.  The icon appears but you can not click on it.